# Как разбить класс на несколько отдельных классов?

Tags: java, ооп, ссылки

Пишу GUI калькулятор на Java. Создал класс Panel, в котором реализовал цифровую панель и кнопки основных действий. Хочу добавить функционала, но код класса Panel становится трудно читать (для новичка). Можно обойтись комментариями для отделения отдельных функций, но хотелось бы изучить структуру Java-проекта. По сути, класс Panel сейчас содержит функционал нескольких классов. Как мне разбить этот класс на несколько, чтобы "Отрисовка панели" была в классе Panel, а реализация кнопок и ручного ввода с клавиатуры в других, и связать эти классы между собой? Буду благодарен за пример кода. Вот как выглядит класс Panel

```
package com.calculator.main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private JButton numbers []= new JButton[10];
    private Font main_font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD,20);

    private JTextField output = new JTextField();

    private JTextField log = new JTextField();
    private JButton backspace = new JButton("C");
    private JButton equ = new JButton("=");

    private JButton plus = new JButton("+"), minus = new JButton("-"), div = new JButton(":"), multy = new JButton("*");

    private  int first_velue;
    private String operation;


    public Panel(){

        setLayout(null);
        setFocusable(true);
        grabFocus();

        numbers[0]= new JButton("0");
        numbers[0].setBounds(70, 250, 50,50);
        numbers[0].setFont(main_font);
        add(numbers[0]);
        for(int x = 0; x<3; x++){
            for (int y =0; y<3;y++){
                numbers[x*3+y+1]= new JButton((x*3+y+1)+"");
                numbers[x*3+y+1].setBounds(y*(50+10)+10, x*(50+10)+70, 50,50);
                numbers[x*3+y+1].setFont(main_font);
                add(numbers[x*3+y+1]);
            }
        }

        backspace.setBounds(10, 250, 50,50);
        backspace.setFont(main_font);
        add(backspace);

        equ.setBounds(130, 250, 50, 50);
        equ.setFont(main_font);
        add(equ);

        plus.setBounds(190, 70, 50, 50);
        plus.setFont(main_font);
        add(plus);

        minus.setBounds(190, 130, 50, 50);
        minus.setFont(main_font);
        add(minus);

        multy.setBounds(190, 190, 50, 50);
        multy.setFont(main_font);
        add(multy);

        div.setBounds(190, 250, 50, 50);
        div.setFont(main_font);
        add(div);

        output.setBounds(10,10,330,50);
        output.setEditable(false);
        output.setFont(main_font);
        add(output);

        log.setBounds(250, 70, 80, 230);
        log.setEditable(false);
        log.setFont(main_font);
        add(log);

         // Должен заканчиваться класс Panel

        ActionListener l = (ActionEvent button_is_presed)->{
            JButton b =(JButton) button_is_presed.getSource();
            output.setText(output.getText()+b.getText());
        };
            for(JButton b :numbers){
                b.addActionListener(l);
            }

            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                char symvol = e.getKeyChar();
                if(symvol=='+'){
                    first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                    log.setText(first_velue+"");
                    output.setText("");
                    operation ="+";
                }

                if(symvol=='-'){
                    first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                    output.setText("");
                    operation ="-";
                }
                if(symvol=='/'){
                    first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                    output.setText("");
                    operation =":";
                }
                if(symvol=='*'){
                    first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                    output.setText("");
                    operation ="*";

                }
                if (symvol==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    int second_value = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                    if ("+".equals(operation)){
                        output.setText(first_velue+second_value+"");
                    };

                    if(symvol==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
                            String tmp =output.getText();
                            output.setText(tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1));
                    };
                    if ("-".equals(operation)){
                        output.setText(first_velue-second_value+"");
                    };
                    if ("*".equals(operation)){
                        output.setText(first_velue*second_value+"");
                    };

                    if (":".equals(operation)){
                        output.setText(first_velue/second_value+"");
                    };
                };
                if(!Character.isDigit(symvol)){
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    output.setText(output.getText()+ symvol);
                }

            }
            }
            );

            backspace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String tmp =output.getText();
                    output.setText(tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1));
                }
            });
            plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                    output.setText("");
                    operation ="+";
                }
            });

            minus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                output.setText("");
                operation ="-";
            }
        });
            div.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                output.setText("");
                operation =":";
            }
        });

            multy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                output.setText("");
                operation ="*";
            }
        });

        equ.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int second_value = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                if ("+".equals(operation)){
                    output.setText(first_velue+second_value+"");
                };
                if ("-".equals(operation)){
                    output.setText(first_velue-second_value+"");
                };
                if ("*".equals(operation)){
                    output.setText(first_velue*second_value+"");
                };

                if (":".equals(operation)){
                    output.setText(first_velue/second_value+"");
                };
            };

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну где большой код-то? То, что в вопросе, это разве что эпиграф к большому коду  ;) И у вас странное понимание модульности. Она заключается не в том, что код каждого класса короткий, а в том, что каждая сущность оформляется в отдельный класс. Количество строк кода к этому отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я только начал изучать java, поэтому для меня это большой код, а если я добавлю еще определение корня и т.д., то буду искать нужный фрагмент кода очень долго. Можно обойтись комментариями, но комментарии я ставить уже научился)) Поэтому хочу разбить данный код на отдельные классы.

Про модульность почитаю, спасибо.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH вы не тому отвечаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как разбить большой класс на несколько отдельных классов?

Нужно разделять **независимые, самостоятельные сущности** в отдельные классы. Спросите как? Это уже думайте сами. Каждый объект должен выполнять свои определенные функции, так же как и каждый метод выполняет что то конкретное. Вы же методы как то создаете, как то их называете? Вот и с классами все так же, там просто следующий уровень структурирования информации, на уровне самостоятельных объектов.

> чтобы "Отрисовка панели" была в классе Panel, а реализация кнопок и
>   ручного ввода с клавиатуры в других?

На счет данного вопроса - используйте паттерн **MVC**.

- V - отображение информации на экране,
- C - обработка событий (нажатие клавиатуры, клики мыши),
- M - логика калькулятора.

Не думаю, что вам это реально нужно в вашем маленьком проекте. Хотя, на сколько я понимаю, это у вас учебный проект, так что попробуйте переписать на MVC, будет полезно - опыт!

---

А вообще код у вас не большой, не видели вы больших классов.